# Столкновения с моделью в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Создал модель уровня в 3D Max, поместил в Unity. Как в таком случае оптимально сделать физическую модель для уровня?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотря что будет происходить на уровне
Если игрок будет просто бегать, то достаточно "обернуть" препятствия в BoxCollider, это хорошо скажется на производительности, но есть возможность что игрок найдет то место, где вы забыли "обернуть" и провалится сквозь текстуры.
Если на уровне много физики, то лучше выбрать Mesh Collider, но если у вас очень детализированная модель, то это может оказаться слишком дорого.

Более подробно читай [здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Добавь 3D/2D Collider
Это Inspector>Add Component>Box Collider 3D
и дальше располагай как тебе угодно